# How to validate array of uuid in nest js using class validator?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

How to validate an array of **uuid** ?
I'm using the pre-built **ParseArrayPipe** to validate the payload array structure.

```js
@Post(':id/players')
  addPlayers(
    @Body(new ParseArrayPipe({ items: GamePlayerDto, separator: ',' }))
    gamePlayers: GamePlayerDto,
  ) {
    console.log(gamePlayers);
  }
```

```js
export class GamePlayerDto {
  @IsUUID()
  playerId!: string;
}
```

I don't want class validator to check if playersId property is here but only raw value

e.g. this is what my server should received

```json
["73aef2dd-c227-4774-b547-b3117b543863", "73aef2dd-c227-4774-b547-b3117b543863"]
```

Answer (score 17):

You have to set the option - "each: true".

```
export class GamePlayerDto {
  @IsUUID(UUIDVersion,{each:true})
  playerId!: string;
}
```

Accepted UUID Version values -
`'3' | '4' | '5' | 'all' | 3 | 4 | 5;`

Quoting official doc - "Specifies if validated value is an array and each of its items must be validated."

Essentially, The value of playerId is considered as an array and is of type UUID (of specified version) and each value has to be validated.

**UPDATE**

Also update your request handler to:

```
@Post(':id/players')
  addPlayers(
    @Body(ValidationPipe))
    gamePlayers: GamePlayerDto,
  ) {
    console.log(gamePlayers);
  }
```

`ValidationPipe` is a default pipe in NestJS that works hand in hand with class validator. It will validate the incoming request body/params etc.. and rejects if it does not meet the set conditions in the DTO.

Answer (score 5):

you can use it

```
@IsUUID(undefined, {each:true})
providers: string[]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write a custom class-validator. Which verifies that the array received by the server only contains UUIDs

```
import {
  registerDecorator,
  ValidationArguments,
  ValidationOptions,
} from 'class-validator';

import validator from 'validator';

export function IsUuidArray(validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
  return function (object: Object, propertyName: string) {
    let fakeElements = [];
    registerDecorator({
      name: 'IsUuidArray',
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName: propertyName,
      options: validationOptions,
      validator: {
        defaultMessage(): string {
          return `[${fakeElements}] is not uuid`;
        },
        validate(value: string[], args: ValidationArguments) {
          fakeElements = [];
          let isOnlyUuid = true;
          value.forEach((element) => {
            const result = validator.isUUID(element);
            if (!result) {
              isOnlyUuid = result;
              fakeElements.push(element);
            }
          });
          return isOnlyUuid;
        },
      },
    });
  };
}
```

And you can use it like this

```
export class CreateInsuranceCommand {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsUuidArray()
  @IsOptional()
  @IsArray()
  providers: string[];
}
```

I used [validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) to check if string is uuid

Comment: Not a fan of naming that "result". Why not `isValidUUID`?

Answer (score 0):

`ParseArrayPipe` does not validate the values and it only transforms the values into an array. Use `ValidationPipe` to check whether it is uuid.